# Manually setting folder permissions for Orchard CMS

Tags: permissions, orchardcms

I need to reapply permissions to the folders under app_data since my app pool user changed. When I look at another site I've got it's got special permissions - not just read/write.

Is there a script to re-apply this - or what special permissions do I need to apply?

thanks!

Comment: As long as the pool user can write and create files, you're fine.

Comment: Hi Bertrand - can I just blanket the top level folders and all sub folder/files with read/write?  Just dont want to open something up that shouldnt be.

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. The folders that need write permissions are app_data, modules, themes and media (and actually, modules and themes only if you need to be able to add new modules and themes from the admin)

Comment: got it - thanks Bertrand.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't opening up something I shouldnt. (I did realize which folders were in question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a description in [`Orchard` documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file#RunningtheSiteUsingIIS) specifying which folders should have which rights.

From the document:

> You might have to set read/write permissions for the account that is configured as the identity for the IIS application pool on the following folders:
>  - Modules. This is required if you want to install modules from the gallery. (We recommend that you remove the read/write permissions for production sites.)
>  - Themes. This is required if you want to install themes from the gallery. (We recommend that you remove the read/write permissions for production sites.)
>  - AppData_. This folder is where Orchard stores site settings.
>  - Media. This folder is where Orchard stores media files (images, etc.).